# Counting each line intersection on a grid of polygons in geopandas

Tags: python, numpy, geopandas

I have a large dataset (~20000) of past storms over 40 years that have a list of central points over 3-hour intervals. I'm trying to overlay a mesh-grid onto a large area from which I would like to count the number of times each storm has passed over any given grid cell, however my current implementation only tracks the position at those three-hour intervals, leading to some instances where the track jumps a grid space when it should also be counted.

I am trying to address this problem using geopandas instead to create a lineseries for each storm track, and then perform an intersection against the mesh grid, however, I cannot find any functional implementations that allow me to do so.

To create the grid in geopandas, I am using the [following solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37055245/7537290) from a previous question:

```
lonCount = ((plotExtent[1]+360) - (plotExtent[0]+360)) * gridResolution
latCount = ((plotExtent[3]) - (plotExtent[2])) * gridResolution

lons = np.linspace(plotExtent[0], plotExtent[1], lonCount)
lats = np.linspace(plotExtent[2], plotExtent[3], latCount)
# Store the meshgrid in polygon format
xlines = [((x1, yi), (x2, yi)) for x1, x2 in zip(lons[:-1], lons[1:]) for yi in lats]
ylines = [((xi, y1), (xi, y2)) for y1, y2 in zip(lats[:-1], lats[1:]) for xi in lons]
# Save as a Shapely object, then store in geopandas
grids = list(polygonize(MultiLineString(xlines + ylines)))
polyFrame = gpd.GeoDataFrame(grids)
```

This creates a geoDataSeries of ~5600 polygon objects. I then loop through each of my storm objects to strip out the lat/lon list pairs, and convert them into a shapely LineSeries object, which is then read into geopandas as such:

```
polyLine = LineString(list(zip(storm_lons, storm_lats)))
coord_tests = gpd.GeoSeries(polyLine)
```

My goal from here is to simply do something like this:

```
I = coord_tests.intersects(polyFrame)
```

To collect a list of polygons that the LineString intersects with, however, this prompts the following error:

```
AttributeError: No geometry data set yet (expected in column 'geometry'.)
```

I'm wondering if I have something formatted incorrectly here, am passing the call incorrectly to this function, or if there is a more efficient way to accomplish what I am trying to do here.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
polyFrame = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=grids)
```

:-)