# How can I create grid of coordinates from a center point in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, shapely, pyproj

Is there a method to extract a grid of coordinates (purple dots) from a center coordinate, with a 100 meters distance between each coordinate for example?

[image]

For example having an input of latitude and longitude center coordinate (red dot):

```
lat = 40.8264859
lon = -3.6805897
```

In a function that then returns you a list of lists or array with the corresponding lat,lon grid with 100 meters from each other, and a max number of coordinates away from the center point (in this image case that value would be `2`). For example:

```
def get_grid_of_coordinates_from_center(lat, lon, meters_between_coor, coors_away_from_center):
    ...
    return list_of_lists
```

Comment: I would start from the center, compute the lower left corner from there, then use [linspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37041377/numpy-meshgrid-to-shapely-polygons) to make an array of evenly spaced lat/lon values that you can pass to shapely

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I generate a regular geographic grid using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40342355/how-can-i-generate-a-regular-geographic-grid-using-python)

Comment: check the approach that I share. its completely vectorized and should solve your problem. Let me know incase of any confusion.

Answer (score 7):

Try this vectorized approach. The equation to offset a lat-long with meters is inspired from [this link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2951/algorithm-for-offsetting-a-latitude-longitude-by-some-amount-of-meters) on stack exchange -

```
import numpy as np

lat, lon = 50, -10 #center coordinate
dist, coors = 100, 2 #meters, num coordinates in each direction

#Creating the offset grid
mini, maxi = -dist*coors, dist*coors
n_coord = coors*2+1
axis = np.linspace(mini, maxi, n_coord)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(axis, axis)


#avation formulate for offsetting the latlong by offset matrices
R = 6378137 #earth's radius
dLat = X/R
dLon = Y/(R*np.cos(np.pi*lat/180))
latO = lat + dLat * 180/np.pi
lonO = lon + dLon * 180/np.pi

#stack x and y latlongs and get (lat,long) format
output = np.stack([latO, lonO]).transpose(1,2,0)
output.shape
```

```
(5,5,2)
```

Let's plot to see the grid of points and to confirm that the points are properly distributed around the center lat long.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

points = output.reshape(-1,2)
x = points[:,0]
y = points[:,1]

plt.scatter(x,y)              #<- plot all points
plt.scatter(50,-10,color='r') #<- plot the center lat long
```

[image]

---

## EXPLANATION

I break the above steps down into separate functions (and use `np.vectorize`) for ease of understanding.

1. First you need a vectorized function that takes in (lat, long) and offsets it by meters in both X and Y directions.
2. You need to create an `offset_grid`

   - You can start by using `np.linspace` to create a range from start to end with the required number of points
   - Next, you can use this to create a grid with X, Y matrices, using  `np.meshgrid`
3. With the vectorized function and the `offset_grid` you can apply the lat long offset on each of the values and then reshape to get your (x,y) values for each point in the (n,n) expected matrix.

[image]

Let's start with a function that offsets lat, long with some x and y meters.

```
#Offset any lat long by x, y meters
def lat_long_offset(lat, lon, x, y):
    '''
    lat, lon : Provide lat lon coordinates
    x, y : Provide offset of x and y on lat and long respectively
           This needs to be in meters!
           
    The approximation is taken from an aviation formula from this stack exchange 
    https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2951/algorithm-for-offsetting-a-latitude-longitude-by-some-amount-of-meters
    '''
       
    #Earth’s radius, sphere
    R=6378137

    #Coordinate offsets in radians
    dLat = x/R
    dLon = y/(R*np.cos(np.pi*lat/180))

    #OffsetPosition, decimal degrees
    latO = lat + dLat * 180/np.pi
    lonO = lon + dLon * 180/np.pi
    
    return latO, lonO

#Create a vectorized offset function
lat_long_offset_vec = np.vectorize(lat_long_offset)
```

Once we have this function ready, we can simply work on the offset grid that we need to apply offsets in all directions to get the relevant point coordinates in lat, long format.

```
#Create offset_grid and return coordinates
def get_mesh(lat, lon, dist, coors):
    #calculate min and max range for coordinates over an axis
    mini, maxi = -dist*coors, dist*coors
    
    #calculate number of points over an axis
    n_coord = coors*2+1
    
    #create an axis from min to max value with required number of coordinates
    axis = np.linspace(mini, maxi, n_coord)
    
    #create an "offset_grid" for X and Y values for both axis. 
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(axis, axis)

    #calcualte offset coordinates for "offset_grid" in meters
    mesh = lat_long_offset_vec(lat, lon, X, Y)
    
    #Transpose to get the (x,y) values for the offset_grid's shape
    mesh_x_y_format = np.stack(mesh).transpose(1,2,0)
    return mesh_x_y_format

output = get_mesh(50, -10, 100, 2)

print('Shape of output grid:', output.shape)
print('Note: 2 values (x,y) for each point in the expected (5,5) grid')

print('')
print('Output coordinates')
print(output)
```

```
Shape of output grid: (5, 5, 2)
Note: 2 values (x,y) for each point in the expected (5,5) grid

Output coordinates
[[[ 49.99820337 -10.00279506]
  [ 49.99910168 -10.00279506]
  [ 50.         -10.00279506]
  [ 50.00089832 -10.00279506]
  [ 50.00179663 -10.00279506]]

 [[ 49.99820337 -10.00139753]
  [ 49.99910168 -10.00139753]
  [ 50.         -10.00139753]
  [ 50.00089832 -10.00139753]
  [ 50.00179663 -10.00139753]]

 [[ 49.99820337 -10.        ]
  [ 49.99910168 -10.        ]
  [ 50.         -10.        ]  #<- Notice the original coordinate at center
  [ 50.00089832 -10.        ]
  [ 50.00179663 -10.        ]]

 [[ 49.99820337  -9.99860247]
  [ 49.99910168  -9.99860247]
  [ 50.          -9.99860247]
  [ 50.00089832  -9.99860247]
  [ 50.00179663  -9.99860247]]

 [[ 49.99820337  -9.99720494]
  [ 49.99910168  -9.99720494]
  [ 50.          -9.99720494]
  [ 50.00089832  -9.99720494]
  [ 50.00179663  -9.99720494]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

might need to check some edge cases (I used numbers that are easy to work with), but this seems to work

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

mid_x, mid_y, max_x, max_y, min_x, min_y,step_size,num_points = 5, 5, 11, 11, 0, 0, 1, 10
x_range = np.concatenate((np.arange(min_x, mid_x, step_size), np.arange(mid_x, max_x, step_size)))
y_range = np.concatenate((np.arange(min_y, mid_y, step_size), np.arange(mid_y, max_y, step_size)))
data = np.array([[x, y] for x in x_range for y in y_range])  # cartesian prod
plt.scatter(data[:, 0], data[:, 1])
plt.scatter(mid_x, mid_y, color='r')
plt.show()
```

plot:

[image]

Comment: This answer assumes the input coordinates and gridding criteria are in the same units. The OP asked for coordinates in latitude,longitude and gridding in meters.